# Are torsion-free modules over principal ideal domains/Dedekind domains projective

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, projective-module, dedekind-domain

An exercise in "Commutative algebra with a view towards Algebraic geometry" by Eisenbud states that a torsion-free module over a Dedekind domain is a projective module (see page $484$, Exercise $19.6$). But I am not able to prove this or find a reference for the result (there are several references for the case when the module is also finitely generated). Can somebody give a hint or a reference for the result?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't true at all.  For instance, $\mathbb{Q}$ is torsion-free but not projective over $\mathbb{Z}$.  I would assume that there's just a typo in Eisenbud and that exercise means to assume the module is finitely generated.

Comment: Without assuming finitely generated, is there any condition when a flat $R$-module is going to be projective, where $R$ is DVR?

Comment: Well, over a DVR (more generally, over a PID or over a local ring) every projective module is free.  Other than that, nothing comes to mind.